# Constant on multiply-connected boundaries for Saint-Venant torsion

Tags: structural-analysis

I am trying to solve the Saint-Venant torsion problem with FEA.

I have read some classic text and stuck in finding the constant value of stress function on multiple boundaries (i.e. closed section with holes).

In many classic texts, it is shown that the value of constant can be determined by evaluate the following equation at each boundary.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone show me how to compute Phi at each boundary based on above equations? 
Thanks!